# Novell client and windows SSO

Tags: windows, sspi, novell

Does the novell gina install a specific security provider that can be used via SSPI?  Does it have to called out specifically or is SPNEGO good enough?  Will that support single sign on if the novell gina is installed on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know SSPI or the low level things, but I think the way the Novell GINA works, is less about Single Sign On, and more about passing through the credentails.

That is, when a physical user (as opposed to a programmatic user) logs in, the Novell Gina uses the credentials and passes them on to the Windows Gina, and any other Gina in line to receive them, until all are done, and everything is logged in.